# How do I securely get an Id_Token for a user securely through Google Credentials? I'm worried a user could change the URL (Using Expo Go/React Native)

Tags: firebase, react-native, security, expo, credentials

*Hello! I am OCD about security for my app and was wondering how to properly login/signup a user with the Google auth provider.*

I have a client ID and secret for that client ID - from Google Credentials - for my app. I know not to put the secret in the client.

The code below works perfectly but I'm unsure if it's safe to generate an ***id_token*** for a user directly without any server code because of this doc from Expo Go:

[image]

Notice it says "be sure that you don't directly request the access token for the user". I don't know what this means exactly.

```
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    clientId:
      "my-client-id-goes-here.google.apps.com",
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (response?.type === "success") {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      const credential = new GoogleFirebase.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        id_token
      );
    }
  }, [response]);
```

Any ideas on how to execute this securely to make sure a user can't change the URL redirect parameters from Google or anything? I'm just not 100% on what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Use an .env file to store your sensitive information. For example in your .env file put

`CLIENTID="my-client-id-goes-here.google.apps.com"`

Then call it like you did above:

```
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
    clientId:
      process.env.CLIENTID,
  });
```